# is it possible to find hidden files on website?

Tags: http, web, type-safety

If I'm hosting a website, say at http://www.example.com, how can I find files that are in the same folder as `index.html` if I DON'T know the filenames?

So for example, if there are these files in there:

```
http://www.example.com/test.txt
http://www.example.com/test1.txt
```

Can anyone see this list of files? If so, how can I hide them, but make each one accessible to someone who knows the names? I don't want to use a password system, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put index.html in that directory, so no files will be listed. If you allow to upload to that directory, so i can upload some php script to list all files in directory. IF you don't know file name, you can try to guess it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use bruteforce tools such as [dirbuster](https://sectools.org/tool/dirbuster/), or you can look at the "/robots.txt" file for some clues on what's on the website.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you should keep in mind that most of web servers nowadays have rights management implemented, so even if there is such file on the server it may not allow you access to it without authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Some hosting providers provide an option to specify whether directory listings are allowed.  If enabled, and a client requests a URL for a folder that does not contain a default HTML file (index.html, default.html, default.aspx, etc), then the web server will serve up an HTML file containing a listing of the files in that folder.  It is rare that this option is ever enabled, though.

Answer (score -2):

but you should be accurate while inserting names of files in URL or else you can use pen-test tool which will list out some of the names for free.for attempts ot full listing of files you'll need to be a paid member i guess